# Titanium Schedule Timer runs in background service

Tags: iphone, titanium

I am creating an **iphone** application using titanium appcelerator. I'd like to alert my user every 12 hours like an alarm notifier ..

I can able to run a **"scheduled background service"**  [**[bg service link]**](https://gist.github.com/jonalter/1184855),  But the problem is, my "background service" calls only after i pause the app from foreground and the main problem is, If i exited the application,  "background service" stops abrubdly..

i need to run it all time .. what should i do for it..?

Thanx in advance .